# Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal-compatibility' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am experiencing Typescript errors:

```
Error   TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module 'rxjs/internal-compatibility' or its corresponding type declarations.   
 C:\Path-to-App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\src\tsconfig.json,
 C:\Path-to-App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\src\tsconfig.json,
 C:\Path-to-App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\node_modules\rxjs\src\tsconfig.json,
 C:\Path-to-App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\src\tsconfig.json,
 C:\Path-to-App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\src\tsconfig.json 
 C:\Path-to-App\node_modules\rxjs-compat\operator\throttleTime.d.ts 
 2  Active
```

Devkit uses a different version of `rxjs`

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.5
| +-- @angular-devkit/architect@0.1303.5
| | `-- rxjs@6.6.7
| +-- @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1303.5
| | `-- rxjs@6.6.7
| +-- @angular-devkit/core@13.3.5
| | `-- rxjs@6.6.7
| +-- inquirer@8.2.0
| | `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
| `-- rxjs@6.6.7
+-- @angular/cdk@13.3.6
| `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
+-- @angular/cli@13.3.5
| `-- @angular-devkit/schematics@13.3.5
|   `-- rxjs@6.6.7
+-- @angular/common@13.3.6
| `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
+-- @angular/core@13.3.6
| `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
+-- @angular/forms@13.3.6
| `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
+-- @angular/material@13.3.6
| `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
+-- @angular/router@13.3.6
| `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
+-- @azure/msal-angular@2.3.0
| `-- rxjs@7.5.5 deduped
`-- rxjs@7.5.5
```

I do see the `rxjs/internal-compatibility` in the path:

```
C:\Path-to-App\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\internal-compatibility\
```

I am new to typescript and not sure how to resolve these reference issues. How do set the alias i believe is the term I'm looking for. To the directory it needs to reference? Or is there something wrong with my `node_modules`?

My stack is .Net 6 Angular 13 typescript 4.6.4

Comment: How do you use throttleTime in code? rxjs-compat
 is used for migration purposes, either install it correctly, or change your rxjs usage to latest, like below
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs';